# `aws s3 ls <bucket-name>` works on local machine, but on EC2 NoSuchBucket error

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

When I use the command `aws s3 ls` on both my EC2 machine and local Macbook, the output is the same, it lists all the buckets in S3. `aws configure` has the exact same ID, secret key, region, output format.

However, when I actually go to look at the contents of a bucket using the command `aws s3 ls <bucket-name>`, my local machine correctly lists all the items, while my EC2 responds with:

`A client error (NoSuchBucket) occurred when calling the ListObjects operation: The specified bucket does not exist`.

The EC2 machine can clearly communicate with the account correctly, but why would it not be able to list bucket contents when my local machine can? I don't see any permissions that would let my machine access it when the EC2 can't.

Comment: Make sure you spelled the `bucket-name` correctly. Add `--debug` to the command to get more information.

Comment: Wow, this is extremely weird. It looks like the command was chopping off the first 5 characters, so when I change the bucket name to '.....bucket-name' it works.

Comment: Try referring to the bucket with `s3://`, for example: `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket`.

Comment: This works, but so does any 5 characters prepended to the bucket name.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer but a workaround. The output of when using `--debug` like helloV suggested showed that the command was using the bucket name with the first 5 characters removed. When I added 5 random characters to the front of the bucket name (like `.....bucket-name` as opposed to `bucket-name`) it works and properly lists the content. If anyone has any clue as to why this is I would like to know.